# Encoding in developing a R package

Tags: r, encoding, ascii

While I run `devtools::check()`, one warning appears:

`checking data for non-ASCII characters ... WARNING
  Warning: found non-ASCII string
  'Tanaid<c3><a6>' in object 'data_m'`

I did the following check

`library(stringi)`

`stri_enc_mark("Tanaid<c3><a6>")` which shows "[1] "ASCII""

and `all(stri_enc_isutf8('Tanaid<c3><a6>' ))` which shows "[1] TRUE"

**UPDATE**

I followed up the comment, and attempted to convert the string from native encoding to ASCII.

I did `iconv("Tanaid\xc3\xa6>", "native", "UTF-8")`

However, `iconv` does not take native encoding and reports `Error in iconv("Tanaidæ>", "native", "UTF-8") : 
  unsupported conversion from 'native' to 'UTF-8'`

`iconv("Tanaid\xc3\xa6", "latin1", "ASCII")` or `iconv("Tanaid\xc3\xa6", "latin2", "ASCII")` also does not yield the right string.

A better solution is `stri_trans_general("Tanaid\xc3\xa6", "latin-ascii")` which does the work.

Comment: The error messages escapes non-ascii characters in those greater than/less than symbols. They aren't actually in the text. That is equivalent to `stri_enc_mark("Tanaid\xc3\xa6")`

Comment: Thank you!! Yes, it is the case.